# Need handholding installing slider-pro via NPM

Tags: npm, gulp, zurb-foundation, bower

I am looking to use slider pro in my project but can't for the life of me figure out what steps I am missing.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/slider-pro

I can install it via NPM as a dependency but then what? I am very new to gulp and never have added in a task which I think is what i need to do.

Using Foundation 6 with Gulp, bower, jade, sass on a linux OS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is wrong? Did you add the suggested CSS and JS files to your project? If so, you should be able to run `gulp serve` to see the rendered code...

Comment: I wasn't properly including the css and js like you said, also I read more about what the npm install actually does. Thanks for the clue!